# data from serveral datasources which include jdbc,api(json) can be merged and paged queried

Tags: java, memory, merge, pagination, resultset

I have three datasources from which data can be queried.
the data may have different columns, but share filters.

When merge three datasources result records with share filters,the java application may be suffer from out of memory problem. If I use a pagination or limit , I can't get the exact page data and total records number  . merging records with external files may cause performance issues.  I have no idea how to address this.

sample data follows:

**jdbc**: `select date,region,a , b from t where date between '2017-08-01' and '2017-08-19' and region in ('1100','2000')`

**presto**:  `select date,region,c , d from t where date between '2017-08-01' and '2017-08-19' and region in ('1100','2000')`

**api**:  `[{date:'2017-08-01',region:'NewYork',e:'abc@twitter.com',f:'18'},{{date:'2017-08-02',region:'Sydney',e:'efg@twitter.com',f:'22'}...]`

date and region column results may be different.  Merging large result records will be tricky. any help are appreciated in advance.

Comment: format and remove unnecessary details

Comment: What is your concrete question?